# MongoDb 2.6.1 Error: 17444 - "Legacy point is out of bounds for spherical query"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

After upgrading MongoDb to 2.6.1 in my System n i get sometimes the following error:

> Legacy point is out of bounds for spherical query

ErrorCode 17444

Here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/geoquery.cpp#L73
I can see that this is raised by mongo db due to some invalid data.

```
// The user-provided point can be flat.  We need to make sure that it's in bounds.
if (isNearSphere) {
    uassert(17444,
            "Legacy point is out of bounds for spherical query",
            centroid.flatUpgradedToSphere || (SPHERE == centroid.crs));
}
```

But currently i can't figure why and how to prevent it.

My Code looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<BsonValue> cids = companyIds.ToBsonValueArray();


    return Collection.Find(
                            Query.And(
                               Query.In("CompanyId", cids),
                               Query.Near("Location", location.Geography.Longitude, location.Geography.Latitude, location.Radius / 6371000, true))).ToList();
```

Stacktrace:

> QueryFailure flag was Legacy point is out of bounds for spherical
>   query (response was { "$err" : "Legacy point is out of bounds for
>   spherical query", "code" : 17444 }).
>        at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadFrom(BsonBuffer buffer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
>        at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings
>   readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions
>   serializationOptions)
>        at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider
>   connectionProvider)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using MongoDB 2.6.1 or higher because the code you're looking at was added as a fix for a [JIRA-13666](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13666) issue.

The problem was that some $near queries would crash MongoDB server when called with legacy coordinates that are out of range.

You're probably sending coordinates that are out of range. The part of the code that checks longitude and latitude when doing $near queries with max distance (`GeoParser::parsePointWithMaxDistance` method in [geoparser.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/65b71020e3f51467a42b13784abb63d87225bd39/src/mongo/db/geo/geoparser.cpp)):

```
bool isValidLngLat(double lng, double lat) {
    return lat >= -90 && lat <= 90 && lng >= -180 && lng <= 180;
}
```

If the coordinates are out of range `centroid.flatUpgradedToSphere` will be false and that will cause the error you're receiving.

You should either change your coordinates to be in range or set `spherical` parameter to false to avoid getting this error.

```
Query.Near("Location", location.Geography.Longitude, 
           location.Geography.Latitude, location.Radius / 6371000, false)
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. So if i understand you right, the problem might be their for a longer time and the update to 2.6.1 only reveals it because of that assert. Right?

I'll check wether i can get some logs of error szenarios perhaps i've previous errors resolving radius and or coordinates

Comment: @BoasEnkler I don't really know how log this issue existed, but in JIRA the affected version is 2.6, so I guess that's a bug that was only "recently" introduced.

Comment: I mean that I probably had a bug for longer times when calculating coordinates and the error was only revealed by update. (if i understand you right)

Comment: @BoasEnkler sorry I misunderstood you. I guess the problem in your code was there before, but there wasn't a safeguard against that on MongoDB side until now.

Comment: "Perfect". So this would be logical as we have one component which may have from time to time problems resolving coordinates

Comment: Just want do tell that it has proven. The error occured after getting invalid geocoordinates like 

"Location" : { "$nearSphere" : [307173.0, 5063785.0], "$maxDistance" : 0.0023544184586407157 } }