# Error 17444 Legacy point is out of bounds for spherical query

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, spring-data-mongodb

Below are the mongo db documents from a collection "Location"

```
{ _id: "FortWorth", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 32.862029, -97.32298 ] }
{ _id: "Richardson", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 32.930942, -96.626729 ] }
{ _id: "Austin", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 30.307168, -97.747908 ] }
{ _id: "A", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 0.001, -0.002 ] }
{ _id: "B", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 1, 1 ] }
{ _id: "C", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 0.5, 0.5 ] }
{ _id: "D", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ -0.5, -0.5 ] }
{ _id: "Berlin", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 13.405838, 52.531261 ] }
{ _id: "Cologne", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 6.921272, 50.960157 ] }
{ _id: "Dsseldorf", _class: "com.hack.whereru.Location", position: [ 6.810036, 51.224088 ] }
```

My Code:

```
private static final Point DUS = new Point( 13.405838, 52.531261 );

@RequestMapping(value = "/showFromMongos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFromMogoDB() {

    template.indexOps(Location.class).ensureIndex( new GeospatialIndex("position") );

    // prepare data
    repo.save( new Location("A", 0.001, -0.002) );
    repo.save( new Location("B", 1, 1) );
    repo.save( new Location("C", 0.5, 0.5) );
    repo.save( new Location("D", -0.5, -0.5) );

    repo.save( new Location("Berlin", 13.405838, 52.531261 ));
    repo.save( new Location("Cologne", 6.921272, 50.960157 ));
    repo.save( new Location("Dsseldorf", 6.810036, 51.224088 ) );
    List<Location> locations = repo.findByPositionNear(DUS , new Distance(1, Metrics.KILOMETERS) );


    return "Success";
}
```

the "findByPositionNear" works for

```
private static final Point DUS = new Point( 13.405838, 52.531261 );
```

but if I give the co-ordinates of Fortworth, say,

```
 private static final Point DUS = new Point( 13.405838, 52.531261 );
```

it fails with the exception:

> Error 17444 Legacy point is out of bounds for spherical query.

There is one related question which I already researched and it doesn't have enough info.

Is there any alternate way? Or can anyone explain why one works and the other doesn't ?

Comment: Because the points should be longitude, latitude order, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#geojson-point. And -97 is bigger than -90, which would be the  South Pole.

Comment: This question has details on the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484246/mongodb-2-6-1-error-17444-legacy-point-is-out-of-bounds-for-spherical-query

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted already, there is a vaildator on spherical queries which the findByPositionNear and mongodb $near functions uses.

Try

```
Circle area = new Circle(new Point(13.405838, 52.531261), new Distance(radius, metric));
Location l = locationCrud.findByPositionWithin(area);
```

Circle has no such limits.